# const char* name’ previously declared

Tags: c++

```cpp
class MyString:public string
{
    public:
            MyString(){ string();}
            MyString(const char* name){
                string(name);
            }
            MyString(const MyString& a){
                    *this = a;
            }
            MyString(const string& a):string(a){}
            MyString operator()(int start,int end){
                MyString ret(substr(start,end));
                return ret;
            }
};
```

when I write this, it shows that

```
‘const char* name’ previously declared here
   10 |             MyString(const char* name){
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
and  string(name);
      |
```

what should I do?

just like words written above

Comment: what did you expect  this line to do `string(name);` ?

Comment: or this `string();` ?

Comment: 1) Do not tag `C` when you are using `C++`.  2) Why are you deriving from `std::string`?

Comment: btw this is not the right way to provide a new method for `std::string`. Not everything must be a member. And not everything makes sense as overloaded operator. Whats wrong with using `substr` as you can already without `MyString` ?

Comment: And while it's possible, please note that `std::string` was not meant to be inherited. There's no polymorphism in `std::string`.

Comment: `string(name);` declares a `string` called "name". It looks like you could use a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: frankly, the way to fix this code is to not write it at all. You need to tell us what your aim is, what the purpose of this code should be. Only then we can tell you how to do it right.

Comment: you are looking the the member initializer list, and somehow mixed up the syntax for it. But fixing the syntax is only the smaller problem in this code

Comment: Clearly what you are intending is this `MyString(const char* name) : string(name) {}` but as explained above, this is rubbish code. If your string inherits from the standard string, it's not really your string is it?

Comment: The `std::string` class is well-documented and recognized by every competent C++ programmer.  Deriving from `std::string` has little to no benefit, and some would consider it a drawback to derive from `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to write your own string class based in the standard string class then the way to do it is to use *composition* not *inheritance*. Based on the code written above, something like this

```
class MyString
{
public:
    MyString() {}
    MyString(const char* name) : my_string(name) {}
    MyString(const std::string& name) : my_string(name) {}
    MyString operator()(int start, int end) const {
        return my_string.substr(start, end);
    }
private:
    std::string my_string;
};
```